# .gitignore is not ignoring a directory

Tags: gitlab

I've below directory structure in my project

```
my-module/src/main/resources/<my-dir-to-be-ignore>
```

And I've added .gitignore file as my-module/.gitignore and here is the content of the .gitignore file.

```
**/src/main/resources/<my-dir-to-be-ignore>/
```

This didn't work and tried to use the below step

https://digitizor.com/gitignore-not-ignoring-files-how-to-fix/

But when i tried to run the command "`git rm -r --cached .`", I'm getting below error

```
fatal: pathspec '.' did not match any files
```

Answer (score 0):

For testing, try adding a .gitignore directly in resources with, as a content:

```
myDirectoryToIgnore/
```

Then, still in that folder, check it is working with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- myDirectoryToIgnore/aFile
```